# Count the number of times each value is present in an array (php)?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to output the total # of times each value is present in an array. Here is the loop I'm using to get the values:

```
foreach( $EM_Bookings as $EM_Booking){              
    $types = $EM_Booking->get_person()->dbem_types;                     
}
```

Here is the var_dump of `$types` so you can see the array I'm trying to count:

```
string(2) "No" string(2) "No" string(3) "Yes" string(2) "No" string(2) "No" string(2) "No" string(14) "Not applicable" string(2) "No" string(2) "No"
```

I want to output the counts of each unique value, like this:

- No = 7
- Yes = 1
- Not Applicable = 1

I know I need to use array_count_values, but I'm not sure how to combine that with my foreach loop. I tried simply doing this:

```
$counts = array_count_values($types);
```

But obviously that isn't correct. Do I need to merge the array somehow, and then count it? I'm still learning, so I don't quite understand what I need to do next. Thank you!

Comment: Is `$types` an array of strings or is it just a string?

Comment: I think $types is an array of strings. Does `string(2) "No" string(2) "No" string(3) "Yes" string(2)` imply that it is an array of strings?

Comment: do `$types = [];` before the `foreach` and `$types[] = $EM_Booking...` and it will work

Comment: From that output it could be. But without a line break between outputs I can't tell.

Comment: Please do `var_dump($types)` and `var_dump($counts)` then edit your question with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$types` is a string, here is how I would track how many times a value is used.

```
$typeCounter =  array();
foreach ($EM_Bookings as $EM_Booking) {
    $types = $EM_Booking->get_person()->dbem_types;

    if (isset($typeCounter[$types]) === true) {
        $typeCounter[$types]++;
    } else {
        $typeCounter[$types] = 1;
    }
}

var_dump($typeCounter);
```

If `$types` is an array of strings, the code would look like this:

```
$typeCounter =  array();
foreach ($EM_Bookings as $EM_Booking) {
    $types = $EM_Booking->get_person()->dbem_types;

    foreach ($types as $type) {
        if (isset($typeCounter[$type]) === true) {
            $typeCounter[$type]++;
        } else {
            $typeCounter[$type] = 1
        }
    }
}

var_dump($typeCounter);
```